# How do I format a Date field of a .CSV file with multiple commas in a string field

Tags: linux, csv, sed, awk, cut

I have a .CSV file (file.csv) whose data are all enclosed in double quotes. Sample format of the file is as below:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6, column7, Column8, Column9, Column10
"12","B000QRIGJ4","4432","string with quotes, and with a comma, and colon: in between","4432","author1, name","890","88","11-OCT-11","12"
"4432","B000QRIGJ4","890","another, string with quotes, and with more than, two commas: in between","455","author2, name","12","455","12-OCT-11","55"
"11","B000QRIGJ4","77","string with, commas and (paranthesis) and : colans, in between","12","author3, name","333","22","13-OCT-11","232"
```

The 9th field is the date field in the format **"DD-MMM-YY"**. I have to convert it to the format **YYYY/MM/DD**. I am trying to use the below code, but of no use.

```
awk -F, '
 BEGIN {
 split("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC", month, " ")
 for (i=1; i<=12; i++) mdigit[month[i]]=i
 }
 { m=substr($9,4,3)
 $9 = sprintf("%02d/%02d/"20"%02d",mdigit[m],substr($9,1,2),substr($9,8,20))
 print
 }' OFS="," file.csv > temp_file.csv
```

The out put of the file temp_file.csv after executing the above code is as shown below.

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,Column8,00/00/2000,Column10
"12","B000QRIGJ4","4432","string with quotes, and with a comma, and colon: in between","4432","author1,00/00/2000,"890","88","11-OCT-11","12"
"4432","B000QRIGJ4","890","another, string with quotes, and with more than, two commas: in between","455",00/00/2002, name","12","455","12-OCT-11","55"
"11","B000QRIGJ4","77","string with, commas and (paranthesis) and : colans, in between","12","author3,00/00/2000,"333","22","13-OCT-11","232"
```

As far as I am understand, the issue is with the commas in the double quote as my code is taking them into consideration too... Please suggest on the below questions:

1) Does the double quoting all the values in all the fields make any difference? If they make any difference, how do I get rid of them from all the values except the strings with commas in them?
2) Any modifications to my code so I could format the 9th field which in the format **"DD-MMM-YYYY"** to **YYYY/MM/DD**

Comment: You can count from end : `NF-1`

Comment: I would look at using a program designed to manipulate CSV files — probably [`csvfix`](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix).  It has date manipulation functions built-in.

Comment: @kev How do I use **`NF-1`** in my code given above? I am new to `linux` and `awk`. 
@JonathanLeffler I tried to do `man csvfix` and it does nt give me any man pages for this... Please elaborate how can I get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following one-liner:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    split("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC", month, / /)
    for (i=1; i<=12; i++) {
        mm[month[i]]=i
    }
}
NR>1 { 
    gsub(/\"/, "", $(NF-1))
    split($(NF-1), d, /-/)
    $(NF-1)=q "20" d[3] "/" mm[d[2]] "/" d[1] q}1' q='"' file
```

#### Output:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6, column7, Column8, Column9, Column10
"12","B000QRIGJ4","4432","string with quotes, and with a comma, and colon: in between","4432","author1, name","890","88","2011/10/11","12"
"4432","B000QRIGJ4","890","another, string with quotes, and with more than, two commas: in between","455","author2, name","12","455","2011/10/12","55"
"11","B000QRIGJ4","77","string with, commas and (paranthesis) and : colans, in between","12","author3, name","333","22","2011/10/13","232"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend you to use proper CSV parser. For example using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.04/CSV_XS.pm) in Perl will do the job right and in sane way. For example this one-liner:

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -E'$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new({eol=>"\n", allow_whitespace=>1});@m=qw(JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC);@m{@m}=(1 .. @m);while(my $row=$csv->getline(ARGV)){($d,$m,$y)=split("-",$row->[8]);$row->[8]=sprintf"%02d/%02d/%04d",$d,$m{$m},$y if $m{$m};$csv->print(STDOUT, $row)}' file.csv > temp_file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk -F"\"" 'BEGIN { OFS="\"" }{ "date -d "$18" +%Y/%m/%d" | getline $18; print $0; }' yourfile.txt
```

**Output:**

```
"12","B000QRIGJ4","4432","string with quotes, and with a comma, and colon: in between","4432","author1,name","890","88","2011/10/11","12"
"4432","B000QRIGJ4","890","another, string with quotes, and with more than, two commas: in between","455","author2,name","12","455","2011/10/12","55"
"11","B000QRIGJ4","77","string with, commas and (paranthesis) and : colans, in between","12","author3,name","333","22","2011/10/13","232"
```

Comment: could you please explain the code? what does "$18" here stand for? because, when I am using your code, I get an error **sh: +%Y/%m/%d: No such file or directory** and prints the same input file content which I have mentioned in my question