# Bash data processing on certain column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i have a text file in this format:

```
a0,b0,c0,27/Aug/2014:23:58,e0
a1,b1,c1,27/Aug/2014:23:58,e1
a2,b2,c2,27/Aug/2014:23:58,e2
a3,b3,c3,27/Aug/2014:23:58,e3
a4,b4,c4,27/Aug/2014:23:58,e4
```

and at the end i need to come up with

```
a0,b0,c0,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e0
a1,b1,c1,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e1
a2,b2,c2,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e2
a3,b3,c3,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e3
a4,b4,c4,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e4
```

and i have to

```
sed 's/\//\ /g' | sed 's/:/\ /'
```

to format the date

and then i need to do something similar :

```
date -d "19 Aug 2014 13:51:23 6 hours"
```

to get the hour to advance 6 hours

but the problem i stumble upon is how can i get all these actions only on that row?

Comment: on that row or column?

Comment: `sed 's/\//\ /g' | sed 's/:/\ /'` is better written `sed 's/\//\ /g;s/:/\ /'`.  Maybe use multiple `-e` options or a newline instead of the semicolon if your `sed` dialect doesn't like this particular idiom.  But of course, the rest of the task requires something like Awk or Perl, so better to do all the processing there in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
    split($4,t,/[\/:]/)
    mthNr = (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[2])+2)/3
    secs  = mktime(t[3]" "mthNr" "t[1]" "t[4]" "t[5]" 0") + (6*60*60)
    $4    = strftime("%d %b %y %H:%M", secs)
    print
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
a0,b0,c0,28 Aug 14 05:58,e0
a1,b1,c1,28 Aug 14 05:58,e1
a2,b2,c2,28 Aug 14 05:58,e2
a3,b3,c3,28 Aug 14 05:58,e3
a4,b4,c4,28 Aug 14 05:58,e4
```

Comment: +1 for that `match` idiom. Very clever! I used to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21965378/970195).

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -naF, -e '$t = Time::Piece->strptime($F[3], "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M") + 6 * 60 * 60;
                             $F[3] = $t->strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M");
                             print join ",", @F;' input-file
```

#### Explanation:

- [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) is a module that handles dates and times (both formatting and arithmetics).
- `strptime` is the function to parse dates to objects.
- 6 * 60 * 60 is the number of seconds in 6 hours.
- `$F[3]` is the fourth column when Perl is invoked with `-a`, plus `F,` tells it to split columns on commas.
- `strftime` formats the object back to a string.

Comment: Love that `strptime` function! I think I'll see if I can twist some arms to get it added to gawk.

Comment: @EdMorton: Shouldn't be so hard: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html

Comment: The only caveat is that Time::Piece objects are not timezone aware. There are a couple of times per year, in some areas of the world, where 23:58 + 6 hours is not 05:58

Comment: Basically I'd be looking for a function that does what the string manipulation parts of my awk solution do and then whatever mktime()/strftime() do wrt timezone awareness. I've started the ball rolling on comp.lang.awk, lets see where it goes... Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Some `date` formatting through `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," '{gsub("/"," ",$4); split($4,a,":"); cmd="date \"+%d %b %Y %H:%M\" -d \""a[1]" "a[2]":"a[3]" 6 hours \""; cmd | getline var; $4=var}1' file
a0,b0,c0,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e0
a1,b1,c1,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e1
a2,b2,c2,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e2
a3,b3,c3,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e3
a4,b4,c4,28 Aug 2014 05:58,e4
```

#### Explanation

- `-F, -v OFS=","` set comma as input and output field separators.
- `gsub("/"," ",$4); split($4,a,":")` remove `/` on date and slice using `:` as delimiter.
- `cmd="date \"+%d %b %Y %H:%M\" -d \""a[1]" "a[2]":"a[3]" 6 hours \""; cmd | getline var` calculate `$date 6 hours` and format accordingly. Value stored in `var`.
- `$4=var` store in `$4`
- `1` prints

Comment: Make it `if ( (cmd | getline var) > 0 ) $4=var; close(cmd)` and add some error handling to avoid the nasal demons if/when the input file contains an invalid date format or something.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & shell):

```
sed -r 'h;s/.*,.*,.*,(.*),.*/\1/;s/\// /g;s/:/ /;s/.*/date -d "& 6 hours" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M"/e;H;g;s/([^,]*)(,[^,]*)\n(.*)/\3\2/' file
```

Extract the date from the file, use the `date` command to add 6 hours and format the return date, then substitute the new date back into the original line.